# Error initializing a PointLCloudT::Ptr variable using boost's make_shared pointer

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build [this library for supervoxel segmenation.](https://github.com/fverdoja/Fast-3D-Pointcloud-Segmentation) When I try to make it, I get this error:

```
supervoxel_clustering/src/testing.cpp:157:66: error: conversion from ‘boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL> >::type {aka boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>::Ptr {aka std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL> >}’ requested
     PointLCloudT::Ptr subcloud = boost::make_shared<PointLCloudT>();
```

Since this was in the testing.cpp, I tried ignoring this file to build the source. But it died again on:

```
supervoxel_clustering/src/clustering.cpp:406:63: error: conversion from ‘boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<pcl::Supervoxel<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> >::type {aka boost::shared_ptr<pcl::Supervoxel<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘pcl::Supervoxel<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr {aka std::shared_ptr<pcl::Supervoxel<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> >}’ requested
     SupervoxelT::Ptr sup_new = boost::make_shared<SupervoxelT>();
```

What could be going wrong with the boost::make_shared instantiation?

Boost Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1

PCL Version: 1.11

C++14 compiler

edit:

While I don't know why the error was being caused, I fixed it with:

```
PointLCCloudT::Ptr cloud_temp(new PointLCCloudT);
```

Comment: The error comes from the attempt to convert a boost `shared_ptr` to a std one. PCL started the transition to std shared pointers in 2019 I think...